# Nginx Config for Cors - add_header directive is not allowed

Tags: nginx

I am trying add CORS directive to my nginx file for as simple static HTML site. (taken from here http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)

Would there be a reason why it would complain about the first add_header directive saying 'add_header" directive is not allowed here'

My config file sample

```
server {
    if ($http_origin ~* (https?://[^/]*\.domain\.com(:[0-9]+)?)$) {
        set $cors "true";
    }

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        set $cors "${cors}options";
    }

    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        set $cors "${cors}get";
    }
    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        set $cors "${cors}post";
    }

    if ($cors = "trueget") {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    }

    if ($cors = "truepost") {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    }

    if ($cors = "trueoptions") {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        return 204;
    }

    listen 8080;

    location / {
        root /var/www/vhosts/mysite;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`add_header` has to be placed under either `http`, `server`, `location` or `if in location` block.

You are placing in under `if in server`. Move them under the `location` block.

```
server {


    listen 8080;

    location / {
        root /var/www/vhosts/mysite;

        if ($http_origin ~* (https?://[^/]*\.domain\.com(:[0-9]+)?)$) {
            set $cors "true";
        }

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            set $cors "${cors}options";
        }

        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            set $cors "${cors}get";
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            set $cors "${cors}post";
        }

        if ($cors = "trueget") {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        }

        if ($cors = "truepost") {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        }

        if ($cors = "trueoptions") {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            return 204;
        }
    }
}
```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header

Comment: This does not work perfectly, if at all. See https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/.

Answer (score 39):

The rule `if in location` can be bypassed by some tricks, so that you don't have to write/include CORS rules in every `location` block.

```
server {
    set $cors_origin "";
    set $cors_cred   "";
    set $cors_header "";
    set $cors_method "";

    if ($http_origin ~* "^http.*\.yourhost\.com$") {
            set $cors_origin $http_origin;
            set $cors_cred   true;
            set $cors_header $http_access_control_request_headers;
            set $cors_method $http_access_control_request_method;
    }

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin      $cors_origin;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials $cors_cred;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers     $cors_header;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods     $cors_method;
}
```

**This works because nginx will not return a header if its value is an empty string.**

Comment: This actually works indeed.  Should get more credit.  the add_header is actually picky, it will allow `add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;` outside a location block, but blows an error when it's an `Access-control-*` one.  Older versions of nginx also accept those.

Comment: But you are still using if in server.

Comment: @MohitSingh This is exactly the answer of how to use `if` in server block for the question! If use `if in location`, you have to write/include the same rule for all `location` blocks which need CORS headers. Furthermore, `if in location` is not suggested unless you are fully aware of [If is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, let me say that after looking around the web, I found this answer popping up everywhere:

`location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}`

However, I have decided to answer this question with a separate answer as I only managed to get this particular solution working after putting in about ten more hours looking for a solution.

It seems that Nginx doesn't define any [correct] font MIME types by default. By following [this tuorial](https://github.com/fontello/fontello/wiki/How-to-setup-server-to-serve-fonts) I found I could add the following:

```
application/x-font-ttf           ttc ttf;
application/x-font-otf           otf;
application/font-woff            woff;
application/font-woff2           woff2;
application/vnd.ms-fontobject    eot;
```

To my `etc/nginx/mime.types` file.

As stated, the above solution then worked. Obviously, this answer is aimed at sharing fonts but it's definitely worth checking to see if the MIME type is defined (correctly) for any other resource you're struggling with too.