# Is is possible to define a single nginx location in two separate blocks?

Tags: nginx

Is is possible to define a single nginx location in two separate blocks?

For example:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name someserver;

  location / {
    proxy_cache off;
  }

  location /assets {
    proxy_cache mycache;
  }

  # What do I need to do to get this second root location
  # to append to the 1st? If it's even possible.
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://foo;
  }
}
```

The idea is that the root location then effectively becomes:

```
location / {
  proxy_cache off;
  proxy_pass http://foo;
}
```

If you'd like to know more about the *why*, read on.

---

### Background:

I'm running a GitLab Omnibus installation. According to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#inserting-custom-nginx-settings-into-the-gitlab-server-block), an admin an inject custom nginx config to the GitLab server block.

However, this injection adds things to the end server block rather than a specific location block.

So if I try to inject `include my_config.conf;`, I'll get:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name someserver;

  location / {
    proxy_cache off;
  }

  location /assets {
    proxy_cache mycache;
  }

  include my_config.conf;
}
```

and if I try to include `location ^~ / {\n  include my_config.conf;\n  }\n` I'll get:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name someserver;

  location / {
    proxy_cache off;
  }

  location /assets {
    proxy_cache mycache;
  }

  location ^~ / {
    include my_config.conf;
  }
}
```

which then causes the nginx config to fail with a `duplicate location "/" in /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf:106` error.

**Note:** `my_config.conf` contains `add_header` stuff for CORS, so it needs to be [in a location block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27955893/1354930).

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to understand how [`nginx` processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html). But location blocks are **not** additive and must be individually complete. You can place certain statements in the `server` block and allow individual `location` blocks to override as required (e.g. `proxy_cache`).

Assuming that all of your URIs are proxied, you could use something like this:

```
proxy_cache off;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://foo;
}
location /assets {
    proxy_cache mycache;
    proxy_pass http://foo;
}
```

Common statements can be offloaded to an `include` file.